# How to remove a field from $_SESSION

Tags: php

How is it possible to completely remove a variable in the `$_SESSION` array?

I'd like, for example, to remove the variable `$_SESSION['id']` so if i write a foreach i will never see something relative to the `$_SESSION['id']` variable.

It seems that `unset()` clears all the variables contained in `$_SESSION`, so i can't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `unset` it like

```
 unset($_SESSION['id']);
```